# jQuery Text Editor: Remove pasted formatting that is not allowed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, text-editor

I am using the jQuery Text Editor, a wysiwyg editor to create rich formatted HTML in a textarea input.

I can initiate the editor in my javascript code and allow / disallow certain formatting options. But when I copy & paste text from somewhere else (Word, E-Mail client, etc.), it keeps all the formatting, even if I disallowed this particular formatting option in the editor.

Is there any smart way to strip all HTML formatting that I disallowed? Or even better can I tell the editor to strip disallowed formatting automatically that is pasted?

This is the code to create the editor. If I copy for example colored text, it keeps the HTML format for text color in there, even though I disallowed the color option:

```
$("#myTextarea").jqte({

  // only allow italic, bold, line break and links 
  "i":true,
  "b": true,    
  "br": true,
  "link":true,
  "source":true,

  // disallow everything else
  "button":false,
  "center":false,
  "color":false,
  "fsize":false,
  "fsizes":false,
  "funit":false,
  "format":false,
  "formats":false,
  "indent":false,
  "linktypes":false,
  "left":false,
  "ol":false,
  "outdent":false,
  "p":false,
  "placeholder":false,
  "remove":false,
  "right":false,
  "rule":false,
  "sub":false,
  "strike":false,
  "sup":false,
  "u":false,
  "ul":false,
  "unlink":false,
 });
```

Comment: this seems to be a bug or missing feature in your plugin. fix, extend the copy/paste thing in the jquery plugin - maybe you want to contact the plugin author. On other side you can strip off specific html tags server side... which is recommended to do anyways

Comment: I am now using http://ckeditor.com/ because it handles the pasting of third party text way better.